# How do I display a newly saved image using opencv from Flask in the static folder?

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I'm trying to take image input and do some processing on it before displaying the output on the webpage. However, when I try a different image, the older image is displayed instead of the new one.

Here are the code snippets:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

import pro

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    n = '/home/vivek/Desktop/CL3/d/booth/trial/uploads/up.jpg'

    a = pro.pro(n)

    return render_template("out.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The process code:

```
import cv2


def pro(p):
    img = cv2.imread(p, 1)

    # some process here

    path = '/home/vivek/Desktop/CL3/d/booth/trial/static/'
    cv2.imwrite(str(path) + 'out.jpg',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    np = '/home/vivek/Desktop/CL3/d/booth/trial/static/out.jpg'

    return np
```

And finally the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>OUTPUT</h2>
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='out.jpg')}}" alt="OUTPUT" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess is not the full code. Tell is how you try with different image?

Comment: I just replace the image in the 'uploads' folder with a new one, but apparently, it does not change.

Comment: Saving in static folder and serve the image via static is not the best practice. May be the image is cached by browser and display the same image. I suspect the image changed after consequent refreshes ?

Comment: The image did not change after refreshing numerous times, however, it did change when I cleared the browser cache. What do you suggest to remove this bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable cache

```
def process():
    ....
    resp = make_response(render_template('out.html'))
    resp.cache_control.no_cache = True
    return resp
```

**Updated**

```
class MyFlask(Flask):
    def get_send_file_max_age(self, name):
        if name == 'out.jpg':
            return 0
        return Flask.get_send_file_max_age(self, name)

app = MyFlask(__name__)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not solving the problem.

Comment: Just checked, under 'Response-Headers' for 'Cache-Control' it says "no-cache"

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: No it's not, it says "max-age=43200", public

Comment: Also what do you think is the reason for out.jpg being unreadable. Is it a problem with opencv?

Comment: Ok, can you figure out the problem please?

Comment: This way we can give the time very less also please hard refresh your browser....

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, where do I put the updated code?

Comment: after `import pro` delete this line `app = Flask(__name__)` and include my updated code over there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145469/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-vivek-giri).

Comment: I can't, don't have enough reputation

Comment: I think I invited you. Can't you able to join ?