# Endpoint which returns send_file not called again

Tags: python, http, flask

I am writing a Flask app in which I have an HTTP endpoint which returns a send_file of an image I create in the function. Unfortunately, it seems the browser caches that image and doesn't even call the endpoint again, loading the original image on subsequent reloads.

Any idea why this is happening and what the fix might be?

Comment: Can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44259169/3762142 ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Thanks for the quick response! Tried extending Flask as you suggested and, unfortunately, no luck. :/

Comment: Okay. Make sure to delete cookies and cache and try.

Comment: D'oh!! Of course, forgot to clear cookies. That did the trick. Awesome solution Raja. If you answer the question I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll make the answer now. Before that `send_file` also has the parameter called `cache_timeout`. So can you revert your code and do `send_file('filename', cache_timeout=0)` ?

Comment: Yup, that works as well. That solution is definitely much better than overriding the Flask function. Should have checked the docs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_file` has the option called `cache_timeout` use that to get rid of browser cache problem.

```
send_file('filename', cache_timeout=0)
```

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work but last time I checekd the API is not changed. However I suspect that when we set cache_timeout to None it will uses the  `send_file_max_age_default` and that default value is 12 hours so but my biggest question is the program assume the cache_timeout as None even though we set to `0`. 

Let me know if you find any workaround regarding this.